# C# EF Core LINQ Table Joining with Alias

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I show data by simply bind gridcontrol with EF datacontext.

```
this.gridRateManager.DataSource = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate.Local.ToList();
```

I already have my own function to populate whatever columns I want to show for the gridcontrol, all I need is to make sure column name match data inside context. Here's my models.

```
[Index(nameof(IdSubProduct), nameof(EffectiveDate), IsUnique = true)]
internal class modelDataProductSubProductRate
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string IdSubProduct { get; set; }
    public DateOnly EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }

    public string? IdCustomer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdCustomer")]
    public virtual modelLibraryCustomer Customer { get; set; }
}

[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
internal class modelLibraryCustomer
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public ICollection<modelDataProductSubProductRate> SubProductRate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create an alias select in my method LINQ as below.

```
this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate
.Include(c => c.Customer)
.Select(pr => new { CustomerName = pr.Customer.Name, pr.IdSubProduct, pr.EffectiveDate })
.Where(pr => pr.IdSubProduct == this.parameter.Id.ToString())
.OrderByDescending(pr => pr.EffectiveDate).ToList();
```

And I got error of this.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The expression 'c.Customer' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection
```

Back then I can accomplish this join by using .FromSQL query but with virtual string property of only the field name I need. But it makes my insert data failed due to property difference. Now that the insert data is working, I still couldn't show data from other table.

Edit :
I checked the DB and relationship is all set. Using the previous LINQ with removed .Include, I got an error like this.

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'p.modelLibraryCustomerId' in 'field list''
```

I tried with manual .FromSQL query which I've used for years.

```
IdSubProduct = new MySqlConnector.MySqlParameter("IdSubProduct", this.parameter.Id.ToString());

FormattableString cmd = $@"SELECT spr.*, c.Name CustomerName FROM ProductSubProductRate spr 
    LEFT JOIN LibraryCustomer c ON (c.Id = spr.IdCustomer)
    WHERE (spr.IdSubProduct = {IdSubProduct})";

this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate.FromSql(cmd).ToList();
```

I already include spr.* which is everything including FK IdCustomer.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The required column 'modelLibraryCustomerId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.'
```

Comment: Try to remove `Include`, it is not needed here.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I edited my question, I think there is something I didn't understand yet with the relationship, it seems so strict.

Comment: Sounds like EF is expecting `modelLibraryCustomerId` as a shadow column? probably because your navigation property isn't nullable.

Comment: "The expression 'c.Customer' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access" ... but it looks like a property from what you have included. There must be something wrong with something that you haven't included.